# Delay loading of chat integration for few seconds

Tags: javascript

there is an integration for Smartsupp chat that goes like this:

```
<!-- Smartsupp Live Chat script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
_smartsupp.key = '5eafc30579aa75bb8bcb1c567a44502fc51fcbad';
window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
  var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
  s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
  c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
  c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
</script>
```

And im trying to delay the loading for example 3-5 sec after page is loaded.
If user is jumping from page to page, he wont contact with me anyway.

Any idea how to touch it and keep it working?
I've tried setTimeout but it seems to broke the code and nothing happens at all.

Comment: Where did you try placing the setTimeout?

Comment: Before and inside so:

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("I am the third log after 5 seconds");
},5000);
XXX script 

or start with setTimeout(function(){ XXX script },5000);

Comment: Just be to be clear, you tried surrounding the entire body of the script tag with the timeout?

Comment: Yep, but it seems to break whole script and nothing is loading at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
_smartsupp.key = '5eafc30579aa75bb8bcb1c567a44502fc51fcbad';
setTimeout(() => window.smartsupp || (function(d) {
    var s, c, o = smartsupp = function() {
        o._.push(arguments)
    };
    o._ = [];
    s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    c = d.createElement('script');
    c.type = 'text/javascript';
    c.charset = 'utf-8';
    c.async = true;
    c.src = 'https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(c, s);
})(document), 1000);
```

Try this out. It appears to be working for me.